# use VBA and Selenium to get current url in Chrome

Tags: vba, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to use VBA in Excel to get the url of the last active instance/tab of Chrome? I have searched high and low but can't find anything on the web and am new to Selenium, so can't work it out on my own. Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

So I just had a quick look at this and it seems quite easy, if you have the driver object of your currently open browser in your script.

In this example I open a new instance of the chrome browser, so I have the driver object, and using the "driver.Url" command you get the currently active tab Url.

```
Dim driver As New WebDriver

Private Sub getUrl()
    driver.Start "Chrome"
    driver.Get "https://www.google.com/"
    MsgBox (driver.Url)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I copied your code into a Module and tried to run the Click command but am getting a Compile error. on Dim driver as New webdriver (it doesn't capitalize "webdriver" in my Module, so there may be something wrong there. But, just looking at the logic, it doesn't appear to be what I'm looking for. As it is written, it seems pre-determined that it will return "https://www.google.com/" as that is what was opened. However, if the browser is already opened via a previous search to, say, bbc.com, I want to return bbc.com so that I can paste that into the active cell.

Comment: Am I making sense?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you open the browser without your script then, for example manually? That makes it a bit more complicated as that would mean that you somehow need to get the already existing chrome instance as a driver object in your script.... I'll have another look at it. And concerning the error you get, I assume maybe you did not add the selenium reference in excel? try following this guide if thats the case https://www.kushalstudy.com/blog/how-to-install-selenium-webdriver-for-vba-in-windows/

Comment: Also, have a look at this too. It describes how to do this with java and python but maybe it helps you  https://testsigma.com/blog/executing-tests-on-existing-chrome-browser-instances/

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. Yes, you understand correctly - I want the url of an already-existing chrome instance. I'll have a look at the link you suggest. Thanks again.

Comment: And somehow the Selenium Type Library in Tools=>References became unticked since last time I used it :-P

Answer (score 0):

First, go to `Tools->Reference-> Select UIAutomationClient`, then call the fucntion `Chrome_GetCurrentURL()`

```
Function GetChrome(ByRef uia As CUIAutomation) As IUIAutomationElement
    
    
    'Dim uia As New CUIAutomation
    Dim el_Desktop As IUIAutomationElement
    Set el_Desktop = uia.GetRootElement
    
    Dim el_ChromeWins As IUIAutomationElementArray
    Dim el_ChromeWin As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim cnd_ChromeWin As IUIAutomationCondition

    ' check the window with class name as "Chrome_WidgetWin_1"
    Set cnd_ChromeWin = uia.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ClassNamePropertyId, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1")
    Set el_ChromeWins = el_Desktop.FindAll(TreeScope_Children, cnd_ChromeWin)
    Set el_ChromeWin = Nothing
    
    
    If el_ChromeWins.Length = 0 Then
        Debug.Print """Chrome_WidgetWin_1"" not found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim count_ChromeWins As Integer
    For count_ChromeWins = 0 To el_ChromeWins.Length - 1
        CurWinTitle = el_ChromeWins.GetElement(count_ChromeWins).CurrentName
        If (InStr(1, CurWinTitle, "Chrome")) Then
            Set el_ChromeWin = el_ChromeWins.GetElement(count_ChromeWins)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
    If el_ChromeWin Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No Chrome Window Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set GetChrome = el_ChromeWin
End Function


Function Chrome_GetCurrentURL()

    Dim strURL As String
    Dim uia As New CUIAutomation
    Dim el_ChromeWin As IUIAutomationElement
    Set el_ChromeWin = GetChrome(uia)
    Debug.Print "1-" & el_ChromeWin.CurrentName
    
    If el_ChromeWin Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Chrome doe NOT exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    Dim cnd As IUIAutomationCondition
    Set cnd = uia.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "地址和搜索栏")
    
    Dim AddressBar As IUIAutomationElement
    Set AddressBar = el_ChromeWin.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, cnd)
    'Debug.Print AddressBar.CurrentName
    strURL = AddressBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ValueValuePropertyId)
    Chrome_GetCurrentURL=strURL
End Function
```